# Make the v-list-group show items on hover

Tags: vue.js, hover, vuetify.js

I am new to Vue and I am trying to make the v-list-group show its items on hover, instead of default click.
I have "isHovered" in the subItem, (initially set to false) to trace the mouse hover. I don't know how to show the `{{ childSubItem.title }}` on hover.
Currently using `v-slot:activator="{ props }"` and it shows on click.

```
<v-list>
    <div v-for="subItem in item.content" :key="subItem.title">
        <v-list-group v-if="subItem.content"
                      :value="subItem.title"
                      >
            <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
                <v-list-item link v-bind="props"
                             :title="subItem.title" class="sub-menu" height="40"
                             @mouseenter="subItem.isHovered = true"
                             @mouseleave="subItem.isHovered = false"
                             ></v-list-item>
            </template>

            <v-list-item link :modelValue="subItem.isHovered"
                         v-for="childSubItem in subItem.content"
                         :key="childSubItem.title"
                         :to="childSubItem.href">
                <v-list-item-title>{{ childSubItem.title }}</v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item>
        </v-list-group>
        <v-list-item v-else link :to="subItem.href">
            <v-list-item-title>{{ subItem.title }}</v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item>
    </div>
</v-list>
```

I have tried to use `v-on="on"`
doesn't work

Comment: So this is Vuetify 2 then, if you are using `on`?

Comment: So, I am making a 3 level dropdown menu that dropdown on hover, on the first level I used v-menu and open-on-hover. So, it dropdown on hover. I don't know how to make the v-list-group dropdown on hover. Tried using v-on="on" but doesn't work